# Counter reset not working in Java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield, jtextarea

In my program it has two `JButton` with name `Start` and `Reset to 0` and one `JTextField` and one `JLabel`. When I click to `Start JButton` number of times its show the result in `JTextField`.

If count number is equal to 1 it show message `Start in JLabel` and when count is greater than 1 it show the `Reset to 0 in JLabel`. But the problem is when I click on `Reset to 0 JButton` it reset to 1 but it not showing message `Reset to 0 in JLabel`?

Program is here:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;
import com.alee.laf.rootpane.WebFrame;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Search {

    private WebFrame frame;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JButton btnResetTo;
    private JButton btnNewButton;
    private int count;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Search window = new Search();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Search() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new WebFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 296, 374);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WebFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        btnNewButton = new JButton("Start");
        btnNewButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            private int Qnty;
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                count=e.getClickCount();
                textField.setText(Integer.toString(count));
                Qnty=Qnty+count;
                if(Qnty==1)
                    lblNewLabel.setText("Start");
                else if(Qnty>1)
                {
                    lblNewLabel.setText("Reset");
                }
            }
        });

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 40));
        textField.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        btnResetTo = new JButton("Reset to 0");
        btnResetTo.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                count=e.getClickCount();
                count=0;
            }
        });

        lblNewLabel = new JLabel("");
        lblNewLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));

        GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(frame.getContentPane());
        groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(Alignment.TRAILING, groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(lblNewLabel, Alignment.LEADING, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 260, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(Alignment.LEADING, groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(btnNewButton, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 88, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 36, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(btnResetTo, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 136, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addComponent(textField, Alignment.LEADING, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 260, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addContainerGap())
        );
        groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(25)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(btnResetTo, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(btnNewButton, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 87, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(textField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 69, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(31)
                    .addComponent(lblNewLabel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(73))
        );

        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(groupLayout);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you include the WebFrame class you wrote

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a `ActionListener` instead of `MouseListener` on your buttons - buttons can be trigged in more ways then just clicking on them. See [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to Write an Action Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for more details
2. When reset is called, you actually need to change the components, like you did with `btnNew` - the variables aren't magically linked to the components

Maybe like

```
btnResetTo = new JButton("Reset to 0");
btnResetTo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        count = 0;
        textField.setText(Integer.toString(count));
        lblNewLabel.setText("Start");
    }
});
```